# MVC Extension - Binding a modified Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I'm trying to create a lambda expression to pass to the view via my MVC helper extension to be used.

What I tried is similar to this :

```
Expression<Func<DoubleNumber,DoubleNumber>> expr2 = (DoubleNumber g) => g.Num1;
```

The default expression was passed like this :

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DoubleBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        //int id, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
...
```

The Model class

```
public class DoubleNumber
{
    public int Num1 { get; set; } // tried strings but again they are null
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
}
```

After using the correct expression format still won't be able to use it :
The correct format:

```
Expression<Func<DoubleNumber,int>> expr2 = (DoubleNumber g) => g.Num1;
```

which mentioned in the comments.

**Error:**

```
"the type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. try specifying the type arguments explicitly."
```

Thanks for any help.
Edited 2 - reformed

The Code is proveided :

```
public static class DoubleBoxHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DoubleBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        //int id, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var model = metadata.Model as DoubleNumber;
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        var fieldId = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(fullName);

// I'm going to use something like this instead of "expression" which seems because of the format or parameter or anything else it's producing an error which I mentioned,

    Expression<Func<DoubleNumber,int>> expr2 = (DoubleNumber g) => g.Num1; 

//The line which will cause the error happened

    builder.AppendLine(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expr2 , new {class, etc} )

...
}
```

I also tried some other forms of TextBoxFor like TextBoxFor or tried to make
Expression> each will have some inner issue, and still looking for a neat solution.

Thanks

Comment: Well where is your `DoubleNumber` type defined? Does it *have* a `Num1` property?

Comment: looks as though it is a method which takes in a parameter of type `DoubleNumber` and returns `Num1`

Comment: Yes, It's inside the given link. a simple class with Num1 and Num2 integer properties

Comment: I'm not good at defining expressions, so maybe the structure or passed items should change, I try to edit and paste some pieces from the previous question I had, which will show some other parts of the code.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Expression<Func<DoubleNumber,int>> expr2 = (DoubleNumber g) => g.Num1;`?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson Seems right but, TextBoxFor doesn't accept it saying : "the type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson that was right but still not accepting the expression

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear about the issue

Comment: Is the error coming from within the `DoubleBoxFor` method or from the code calling it?

Comment: In the DoubleBoxFor, Within the StringBuilder.AppendLine (htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expr2, new {@class =""}) , If that was the former "expression" would work fine, Whe I changed it with my own it doesn't work and give the error which I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @LastBye Not quite sure what you mean. Could you maybe post a minimal but complete version of the `DoubleBoxFor` method which reproduces the issue? i.e. Include all the code necessary to have a full method which compiles and causes the issue, but don't include any extra code that's not needed to cause the error.

Comment: Let me post the more complete code

Comment: Not sure I think the problem is casting between Expression<TModel,TProperty> and the inner expression Expression<DoubleNumber,int> and so on, what could be a better solution which part should I change, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite seem to repeat your problem, this would seem to compile just fine;

```
public static class DoubleBoxHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DoubleBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new {bop = 1}).ToHtmlString());
        return null;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlHelper<DoubleNumber> helper = ...
            helper.DoubleBoxFor(g => g.Num1);
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem I can see in your code is that your expression is hard coded to a particular type, while your `HtmlHelper` is generic. Since the method can be called with any type of `HtmlHelper`, and the generic parameters need to match between the expression and the helper, the compiler won't let you compile the code. If you either take a hard coded `HtmlHelper<DoubleNumber>` or as the code above take an expression with matching generic parameters, things compile well.

EDIT: If you want to build the expressions inside the helper, you don't need it to be generic at all;

```
public static MvcHtmlString DoubleBoxFor(this HtmlHelper<DoubleNumber> htmlHelper)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.AppendLine(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(g => g.Num1, new { bop = 1 }).ToHtmlString());
    builder.AppendLine(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(g => g.Num2, new { bop = 1 }).ToHtmlString());
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The most important part here to me is that the extension as you said will target a specific type which is going to show that in a proper way, If you could mention how instead of "expression" in your code I can use "Num1" property of that type, everything is done and that's fine, thanks for your help.

Comment: I can satisfy of it to be generic, but please move your program-side assignment into the extension-side itself, which I could assign each property for example into a different textbox or etc... , thanks +1

Comment: Thanks for all the help and time, whenever you came back please let me know how can I access to my model's property instead of the whole "expression" inside that extension by any possible way.

Comment: @LastBye I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but I added some info to the answer.

Comment: Yes I want to be more specific than generic, the problem here is that we miss the model which I want to get it back from the texboxes.

Comment: Thanks man, maybe I'm wrong , do we have access to the model with this extension after any postback? I tried this in the view @Html.DoubleBoxFor(m=>m) and it's told none of the overloads have 1 parameter. or tried : DoubleBoxFor(Model) also which is the same.

Comment: Dude you helped me a lot on this, please give me the last hint which I could use it my work, In the view we have a model of type DoubleNumber, how the extension should be changed to return the entered result to the given model like : @Html.DoubleBoxFor(m=>m) or ...

Comment: Also Anytime I changed it to use expressions specific in a specific manner to my type I had no success, I want the extension to be specific to my type but also be bindable to my model, tried to explain as good as I can, any other info is appreciated, thanks for all the help and bye.

Comment: In addition to all I told I need a parameter to pass via the View, there should be thousands of this extension in the same view.